# setup.py file not included with package

Tags: python, bloomberg

I am new to Python and I am currently trying to install the Bloomberg python blpapi package.

To do so I first need to install the Bloomberg C++ SDK. In order to do so I have:

1. Downloaded the Windows experimental package from [bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library][1]
2. I also set up the environment variables accordingly
3. Extracted the package to C:\blp\API
4. I then opened command prompt (CMD.exe) and set BLPAPI_ROOT=C:\blp\API
5. Changed directory to package folder: C:\blp\API\blpapi_cpp_3.14.3.1

The problem arises when I now have to run the command to install the package: python **setup.py** install

I get the error "**python can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory**"

I googled the error and found out that each package has to have a **setup.py** file in order to be installed

What does one do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You might have set up your BLPAPI_ROOT to the right path which is the folder containing C++API but you must run `python setup.py install` in the Python API folder.
These are 2 different steps.